# OpenCV pose estimation

Tags: python, opencv

I am running the openCV pose estimation code, but landing up in this error or error in imshow

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-3a690a81ff40> in <module>()
     25         corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
     26         # Find the rotation and translation vectors.
---> 27         rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)
     28         # project 3D points to image plane
     29         imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)

error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\solvepnp.cpp:315: error: (-215) ipoints.isContinuous() in function cv::solvePnPRansac
```

code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

# Load previously saved data
with np.load('path') as X:
    mtx, dist, _, _ = [X[i] for i in ('mtx','dist','rvecs','tvecs')]

def draw(img, corners, imgpts):    
    corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

axis = np.float32([[3,0,0], [0,3,0], [0,0,-3]]).reshape(-1,3)

for fname in glob.glob('imagepath'):
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)
    if ret == True:
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)

        # Find the rotation and translation vectors.
        rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)

        # project 3D points to image plane
        imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)
        img = draw(img,corners2,imgpts)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)

        k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff

        if k == 's':
            cv2.imwrite(fname[:6]+'.png', img)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

kindly, help me out

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921090/solvepnpransac-returns-zero-value-for-rvecs-and-tvecs and here : http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_pose/py_pose.html

Comment: code formatting

Comment: Probably because of `for fname in glob.glob('imagepath')`.